# Copying EMF image in to word from clipboard

Tags: microsoft-word, emf

I have a Java program that generates EMF(enhanced metafile) image and writes it to Windows clipboard. When I paste the image in to MS Word it changes image's scale for some reason. When I paste the image in to PowerPoint it doesn't get rescaled.

I can change the scale back to 100% and then it looks fine again but why is Word changing the scale on it's own? Can I prevent in somehow?

Demonstrated in the image, PP on the left and Word on the right. It's supposed to be a square.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Paste Special? Is there a difference in how Copy works in `doc` and `docx` documents? Which Windows and Office versions?

Comment: I've just ctrl+v but I've just tried Paste Special in Word and I still get the same result. But word actually sees that it is an EMF file. Both are 2007 versions.

Comment: You are in Windows 10? Did you try both doc and docx?

Comment: Yeah, Windows 10. And I've just tried both doc and docx and still get the same